# void(*)() analogue for member function pointer round-trip casting

Tags: c++, casting, standards-compliance, type-safety, pointer-to-member

When one wants to store pointers to functions with different signatures, one might cast them to `void(*)()` (or any other function pointer type) then cast them back to original type before call and afaik C++ guarantees this round-trip to work. But what about member function pointers? Are there any guarantees that round-tripping a member function pointer through another member function pointer of different type (possibly to a member function of different class) will not break something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `reinterpret_cast` round-trip between pointer-to-member types is guaranteed to be valid, as long as you keep it pointer-to-data-member or pointer-to-member-function in both cases.

Quoting C++11:

`[expr.reinterpret.cast]`

> 10 A prvalue of type "pointer to member of `X` of type `T1`" can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type "pointer to member of `Y` of type `T2`" if `T1` and `T2` are both function types or both object types. The null member pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
>
> - converting a prvalue of type "pointer to member function" to a different pointer to member function type and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.

Comment: @CassioNeri :-) I keep the PDF open. And I've read it cover to cover, so I generally remember where to look. But usually it's just luck.

Comment: Beware: The standard and your implementation of choice might disagree here. And while the standard is by definition *correct* your code might not behave as you expect if your compiler does not agree on what should be done

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Do you have an experience with a particular "compiler of choice," or do you mean a general "beware of compiler bugs in obscure cases?" It's a valid comment, anyway.

Comment: @Angew: The implementation of pointer-to-member to functions in VisualStudio has different sizes depending on the design of the inheritance hierarchy. A single class that does not inherit uses the space of a single pointer. A class with multiple inheritance uses twice that size (pointer to the trampoline and possible offset of the `this` pointer). In that particular implementation you cannot roundtrip with `reinterpret_cast`. Then again, I tested and they solved the issue by disallowing `reinterpret_cast` of pointer to functions (at least in the case I tested)

Answer (score 0):

I think so with a `reinterptret_cast`. That's what the standard says (5.2.11/10)

> > A prvalue of type “pointer to member of X of type T1” can be explicitly converted to a prvalue of a different type “pointer to member of Y of type T2” if T1 and T2 are both function types or both object types.71 The null member pointer value (4.11) is converted to the null member pointer value of the destination type. The result of this conversion is unspecified, except in the following cases:
> >
> > — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to member function” to a different pointer to member function type and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.
> >
> > — converting a prvalue of type “pointer to data member of X of type T1” to the type “pointer to data member of Y of type T2” (where the alignment requirements of T2 are no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the original pointer to member value.